# Konjunktiv II – “liefe“ versus „würde laufen“

Tags: subjunctive, verb-usage

To form the Konjunktiv II in the present tense, I have come across a “first rule” as:

1. Verbs such as *sein, haben, werden* and the modal verbs take irregular single word forms *(wäre, hätte, dürfte* etc)

For the other verbs there are two typical guidelines:

2. Most other verbs are formed with *würde + verb* (two word form)
3. Irregular verbs can formed with *präteritum stem + e* and umlaut where possible (single word form).  A student of German is asked to recognize this in the literature, but is not really encouraged or asked to use it

Taking the verb *laufen*, we could potentially have the following two variants of a sentence -

*i) Wenn ich bequeme Schuhe hätte, würde ich schneller laufen.*

*ii)    Wenn ich bequeme Schuhe hätte, liefe ich schneller.*

In my view, if rhythm, intonation is important, then I would consider using *liefe* over *würde laufen* at any time, and also extend this to other verbs *äße* vs *würde essen* etc.

Would this be a correct way of thinking about it in modern German?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that your rule number 2 is wrong in a technical sense.  The Konjunktiv II exists as a synthetic morphological form for all verbs, and *würde laufen* is not a Konjuktiv of *laufen*.

The problem is that for weak verbs, the Konjunktiv II is equivalent to the preterite, since there is no ablaut to mark it: *laufen - lief - liefe*, but *taufen - taufte - taufte*.  That is why for weak verbs, the *würde* form is pretty much always used nowadays (and recommended).

Because weak verbs are type-wise more frequent and productive, this takes over to the strong forms as well, which is why the *würde* construction is becoming very common and almost obligatory for some forms (you'll be looked at strangely if you use *äße* or even *hülfe* or *fröre* in colloquial speech, and they may sound stilted even when written).  For milder cases as *liefe* is one (with less obscure ablaut patterns), both are equally acceptable, IMO, but the actual Konjunctive II sounds quite a bit more formal.

So: rhythm and intonation don't have anything to do with it into it, just paradigmatic levelling and register.

Comment: I'm sure *gänge* is going to raise some eyebrows … (although [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=5,2376,45) records it: *nicht weil es mir jezo eben schlecht in Berlin gänge*)

Comment: Ah, too much ablaut for one sentence :)

Comment: After self inspection, I suspect this might be because the dialect form I would use is _gangert_.

Comment: In singular person 1 and 3, the Konjunktiv II differs from the preterite because it ends with -e: Ich/er lief, Ich/er liefe.

Comment: @RHa yeah, but only for strong verbs. That's the point.